# Intellij IDEA freezing when trying to move files into project

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I try to move a file into a project I have in IDEA it freezes up after displaying the the move file dialog. I've tried searching around but haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: Check the intellij log file https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827517-Locating-IDE-log-files

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  It is also happening when I try to move a file within a project.  Interface just freezes for several minutes.  All you can do is back out.  nothing in log file.  Started happening for me with build #143.1015 on osx 10.10.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using an EAP release version.  The milestone release did not behave like that.

Here is more info on the subject from JetBrains: Please note that EAP builds are not officially supported. Please use released versions from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html if you want stable functioning.

Could be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145305 .

Answer (score 0):

ruku, I'm not sure if the EAP build was your problem, but if you're like me and are using a stable build and cannot upgrade (compatibility issues with others on my project), I recommend the workaround of just creating a new file and pasting the file content in there. It's not very elegant, and requires manual refactoring for any files already referenced within the project, but since you're moving a file into the project you shouldn't have that issue.

Like sday, it happened to me when moving a file within the project. I am not using an EAP Build. I am using 14.1.4, build #IC-141.15.32 build on June 18, 2015. I installed on 2015-09-05 from the main JetBrains page that sday mentioned. I'm using osx 10.11.1.